# How to display ranges in a map legend

Tags: info-visualisation, map-ui

We need to display a map legend that shows ranges of pipe diameters. Currently we have something like this:

[image: Current legend]

The problem with this is that the edge cases are ambiguous. Does 50mm fall in the first or the second category? We could do something like this:

[image: Possibility one]

Even though this reduces the ambiguity, some still remain. In which category is 50.5mm?

Anyone have a good solution for this? Our users are not engineers or mathematicians, so interval notation would not be an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The specific answer to your question is to go with the first solution. That is the **standard cartographic convention**, effectively eliminating the question of where, say, 50.5 goes. As far as where the exact category breaks go (say, precisely 50), *it doesn’t matter*. Users understand that that the categories are functionally fuzzy. For example, obviously 49.999 is one category while 50.001 is another, but users realize that that the two are practically the same. As far as they’re concerned, “50-ish” pipes, including pipes exactly 50 mm in diameter, can be in either category.

The more broad answer to your question is that if you’re worried about ambiguity of your category divisions, then you need to change your category divisions. Cartography texts recommend that you **break your categories at meaningful points** for your users –make divisions related to the users’ tasks or decisions. It may not be necessary for the categories to have neat regular intervals. If your users really need to know if a pipe is exactly 50 mm, then maybe that should be a category of its own. User research will help determine the meaningful categories and breakpoints. How do you users group pipe diameters into operationally “similar” versus “different”? I suspect the roughly exponential scale you’re using now is supposed to reflect this, but is it based on actual user research?

For example, you could put the breakpoints at **natural places of low data** -diameters that characterize relatively few pipes. I would expect there are industry standard pipe diameters, so you make sure no standard diameter is right on the division between two categories. Now there's virtually no ambiguity because there are virtually no pipes to be be ambiguous about. If there are no standards, then find out what diameters exist in the field. Given a statistical distribution of pipe diameters, cartography has mathematical formulas to create categories with minimal variation within each category and maximum variation between categories.

On the other hand maybe pipe diameters gradually grow and shrink over miles of pipe (not very likely, I would think, but it could characterize, say, daily flow volumes, or river sizes). Then maybe your existing divisions are fine. Where is precisely 50? Precisely where the 0-50 code changes to 50-100, implying the diameter goes up in one direction and down in the other. Alternatives to your categories would be **equal intervals, nested means, equal progression** (e.g., a true exponential, but there are other algorithms too), or categories with **equal statistical frequency**.  Which one you use depends on the results of your user research.

For an introduction to cartography, I recommend the classic [*Elements of Cartography*, by Arthur Robinson et al](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471555797), now in its 6th addition (1995). I expect there are other excellent texts of more recent vintage that specifically cover electronic maps.

Comment: Great answer, this addresses the core of the problem

Comment: As for electronic maps, I've not found anything useful even in the British Library, there is a book from the 90s but that doesn't even deal with tilemaps... I always bugged Astrid (the designer of Nokia maps) that we should simply write one :) (I even started its base...)

Answer (score 4):

How about a solution like this:

[image]

Update:

[image]

Compare it with this:

[image]

The reason why there is no sense of ambiguity in all these 3 examples, is because you don't mention the limit twice. You don't say: 0-50 / 50-100 / 100-200 /... you just mention 0 - 5 - 100 - 200 -...

Comment: Looking at the chart 50, 100, 200 and 1000 would be identified as white.

Comment: Nice, but edge values are still ambiguous?

Comment: @Android Hustle: This is just a quick and dirty mockup. You could replace the white space with a black dash.

Comment: I updated my answer. Both are just quick and dirty mockups of course. The values are absolutely not ambiguous in any case. You read from left to right. You start with 0 and as soon as you hit 50, 100, 200,... you get a new value.

Comment: Indeed, **this** is the standard cartographic convention.

Comment: I see what you intended now after your edit, and it's good. But the first image is terrible since there's no clear way to distinguish which interval a threshold number relates to, that is unless you're experienced with cartography, something I'm certainly not. The second image you added was much better.

Comment: Ok I see, even though I don't think your method would work as well for discrete lines (such as pipes), it would work perfectly for polygons (areas). Thanks for your insights!

Comment: @AndroidHustle: "unless you're experienced with cartography, something I'm certainly not". I don't want to be rude, but where I live this is what every kid aged 8 years learns in elementary school. But even without that knowledge, is this not the most natural way to represent this?

Comment: In any case, I believe that the key element to get rid of the sense of ambiguity is to remove the duplication of the limits. Don't use  0-50 / 50-100 / 100-200 /... just use 0 - 5 - 100 - 200 -...

Comment: @BartGijssens Yes of course, and I also got to learn the difference between nouns, pronouns, proper nouns, verbs, adjectives and adverbs. However it's still not something I would assume all my users know, and risk ridiculing them by having the interactive controls relying on the user knowing the difference. I still stand by that the top image is a terrible representation of the dimensions on the chart, there's no clear visual indicator to determine if you should be looking for a purple line or a pink line when searching for a pipe with the dimension of 200.

Comment: @ AndroidHustle: Do you have that same problem with the relief chart that I added? There is no difference between that and the first example.

Answer (score 3):

I've faced similar issues with speed legends on a map system I work on. I finally came to rest with your latter method, however the developers added a tool tip so that a specific piece of road's speed can be seen when hovering. This allows the users to pinpoint exactly where they need to know the pipe size (in your case) and covers you for complicated junctions or transitions between the two.

Comment: That's a nice solution!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about you, but I'd denote pipe diameters with line width rather than colors... it's somehow more logical

What about using textual notation, with the English construct "between"?

- lightblue - less than 50 mm
- blue - between 50 mm and 100 mm
- navy blue - between 50 mm and 100 mm
- etc

It's a bit longish, but it could be shortened.

You know, **it might be true, that a picture is worth a thousand words, but it's a scientific fact that a well-chosen word is worth a million ill-chosen icons.**

**Edit**:

I'm not removing the last sentence for historical reasons, but let's have another phrasing then: **if you can only describe it in words but no pictures, use words.**

And let's add *Raskin*'s argument here from *The Humane Interface, Chapter 6.3: Icons*, http://bit.ly/NTCrCz - where you can find the details on how labels are better instead of desperately searching for a different representation.

And there is a counter-argument as well, in *Jeff Johnson*'s ingenous *Designing With the Mind in Mind*'s *Chapter 4: Reading is Unnatural*, equally supported by science

They don't really contradict each other, it's just the two sides of the same coin. Words are recognized in one chunk for accustomed readers (which most of the people in office jobs are), therefore Johnson doesn't argue about using a single word when you can't find a good icon, he's arguing about using lengthy text instead of some visual metaphor.

Comment: I like your idea, but how would you word it so edge values are not ambiguous? It's still not clear in which category 50mm falls.

Comment: I guess it is, I mean, less than 50 mm is up until 49.99999 I guess, and 100 mm isn't between 50 and 100, it's between 100 and 500. Or you could say, "at least 50 but less than 100", if it's clear

Comment: Taking the term "scientific fact" kind of lightly, aren't we? :)

Comment: @VitalyMijiritsky: Actually, not. Refer to Chapter 6.3 of Jeff Raskin's book ( http://bit.ly/NTCrCz ) where he cites studies conducted by Mayhem, et al, or do an A/B testing, or visit large e-commerce sites, like Expedia. Count the number of icons without explicit, non-hover labels next to them, where it actually matters in revenue. It's surprising that the myth of the icon still lives through after debunked 20 years ago

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines, phrasing the intervals rather than describing them merely by numbers. And I would vote this up if it wasn't for that last sentence, it just hurts my eyes too much to see where the up arrow is.

Comment: @AndroidHustle: actually, there's a label right underneath it which clarifies its use ;) let's not get into the history of writing, and I didn't claim all pictures are bad. I just "summarized" results of A/B testings and what widely respected books wrote in the colliquial style so many people think of UX still. I'm sorry if you feel my summary of Raskin's writing hurts your feelings.

Comment: @Aadaam don't get me wrong, I agree with you. The use of icons instead of descriptive text is trendy, and there's no question that it hurts discoverability in MANY occasions. I was simply referring to the last sentence, not because it hurts my feelings, but simply because I thought it was bad. But you know, different strokes for different folks.. =)

Comment: @Aadaam you know what, don't mind me. I'm just in a bad mood. Need to go for lunch... I like the phrasing of the notation which was your suggestion. I'm being foolish letting myself be annoyed at that sentence, maybe I just don't get it. Either way,  +1 for a good suggestion.

Comment: @Aadaam That very well may be, but calling a meaningless claim such as "a well-chosen word is worth a million ill-chosen icons" a scientific fact is, well, not very scientific. A good icon can be better than bad words and a good word can be better than bad icons. There's no "myth" of the icon, let alone a "debunked" one. There are people who know what they're doing and people who don't. Icons have advantages and disadvantages, and that's precisely what Jeff Raskin is saying.

Comment: @VitalyMijiritsky: With all respect, I disagree. It is a scientific fact that when you choose between icons and labels, labels win on an A/B testing (and that even a good icon is rarely better than a word). There are papers about this, there are reproducible experiments about this, so, it's science. As for the myth, perhaps I wasn't too careful in my wording, but the request for icons based on "a picture is worth a thousand words" is still an issue which needs to be elaborated with nearly every customer. As long as A/B tests show that icons fit you better in your situation, use them :)

Comment: @Aadaam Of course they win in A/B testing, if you test for clarity! Clarity is not the only parameter in UX. Look at your desktop and imagine it with no icons. None. All icons are now replaced with words. Including start button, task bar, the tray and the items on the desktop itself. Your window controls now say "minimze, maximise/restore, close". Now A/B test that with your current desktop, for efficiency, learnability and satisfaction. Everything has its place. Saying that labels are better than icons is likes saying that dropdowns are better than radio buttons. That's not "science", sorry.

Comment: @VitalyMijiritsky: that's called metro UI, and will be installed by default on your next laptop - sorry for being sarcastic. Actually MS invested a lot of A/B testing into this now, it's also strange to me as right today I'm testing outlook.com, but I wouldn't entirely rule this out yet. But I didn't say that icons are ALWAYS worse; I said MOSTLY. This is what the research of MS shows, we might not agree, it might not be as aesthetically pleasing, but this is what it came out in tests. And my latest design (not user-tested yet) included "collapse" and "expand" for panel buttons, no icons

Comment: And I remember a test - albeit this is a bit 'anecdotal', as I can't just refer to some papers, sorry - where they tested how little children are able to handle iPad's homescreen. It turns out, it was more of spatial memory, than icons: it was the position which mattered. But again, no, I'm not saying that icons don't have a place but I guess that our personal preference and relation to swiss design might alter the argument for both of us. Icons, are great, but as I'm using OSX, I concentrate on the color of the minimize button rather than its icon. But again, it might be a personalpreference

Comment: @Aadaam Hate to resurrect this, but since you brought up metro, I couldn't resist :). I just downloaded the metro-styled Office 2013. And the ribbon is plain old ribbon, all of it icons, metro or no metro :). And not just the ribbon - plenty of controls which could definitely be labels are icons, like everything in the topmost bar and more. Metro is not about replacing icons with labels...

Comment: @VitalyMijiritsky: I didn't use O13 yet... I used only Outlook.com and my previous company was so unfortunate that they decided to go with WP7 instead of their own platforms.. meant UXers had to learn WP7 HIG... Perhaps metro guys were thrown out of the O13 department saying it'd be too much change. But again, I'm a bit more lexical than visual, for me, text is important, and I guess it's a personal preference, there are arguments for both sides. Like, I remember a test where the "universal" share icon gained a 0% recognition by 20 participants. It'd have been easier to write "share" instead.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not the labels, the issue is the fact that you use a discrete scale I think.

If you'd like to solve it using the labels only, you'd have to use symbols like ≤ and ≥ with the labels to precisely identify what you mean. So, you'd get this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fT1H78.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

I don't think that that is a very useful solution though. The labels would be harder to comprehend. Instead, you could considder using a continious scale. So, not one blue line piece with two labels, but a continous gradient from blue to red in your case (via as many colors as you need). You can add simple lables to that to indicate values along that scale, in the way Bart Gijssens suggests. The labels would no longer be ambigous, as they would only indicate a value along a continious scale, and not indicate a cutoff point at all.